# How to keep tabs in web.config transforms?

Tags: .net, web.config-transform

We use [Web.Config transforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig) in a Visual Studio 2017 project, but I notice in the output all tabs have been replaced by two spaces. Is there any way to avoid this? Is this configurable anywhere?